# Group By return only one row for each

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, group-by

I have a one table and want group by one column of the table **contract**. But when I try with group by then it returns only one row of each please check Sqlfillder.

Query is:  `Select * from employees group by contract`

[SqlFillder](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/21267/1)

Comment: Can you please add an example what you expected? In SqlFillder I got two rows. That what i expected.

Comment: What do you expect from group by clause?

Comment: What you want using group by clause just tell we can help you

Comment: This is how group by are used generally. Select  contract, count(1) from employees 
group by contract; What output and what fields do you want?

Comment: Is it MySQL or SQL Server? These are different DBMS. You query is valid in MySQL (though it doesn't make much sense), but invalid in SQL Server.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
Declare @employees table  (
  id int not null,
  name char(30) not null,
  [contract] char(30) not null,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);



insert into @employees (id, name, [contract])
values 
(1, 'John', 'full-time'),
(2, 'Mike', 'full-time'),
(3, 'Alex', 'part-time'),
(4, 'Jerry', 'part-time');

Select e.id,e.name,e.[contract] from @employees e group by e.id,e.name,e.contract
```

Comment: in above question unable to get expected result set because contract is defined keyword and it is not able to take as column name..so i mentioned this one in [Contract] and in group by we need to list out columns

Comment: Nishanthi Grashia is right. Your query makes no sense. You simply select * from employees. The group by clause is superfluous and even obfuscating. Moreover your answer doesn't really answer anything.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner in this case i didn't say that my query is giving an answer.I just gave the clear view of correct syntax just observe the question in sqlfidddle.So that u can find out where the syntax gone wrong...

Comment: But there is no syntax error in the original query (at least not in MySQL - unfortunately the request is tagged *both* MySql and SQL-Server). It runs and returns two records, just as it should. In SQL Server using *contract* as a column name isn't the problem either. Here the problem would be that the system demands each column to be either in the GROUP BY clause or be aggregated.

Comment: execute the same table and syntax which was in the fiddler you will find out the problem and how i done the modifications according the requirement

Answer (score -1):

It is rather nonsensical to group, but select *.

You are grouping by contract. So you get one line per contract. Then you want all columns, which is beside the contract the id and the name. You don't specify which id and which name you want to see per contract, so you get random matches.

A good rule is to specify for each column you select, to be either grouped by (as contract in your example) or aggregated (MIN, MAX etc.).

```
Select contract, GROUP_CONCAT(name), id from employees group by contract;
```

Contract is grouped by; name is aggregated in this example. That's how it shall be. But id is neither grouped by, nor aggregated in my example. So according to the rule, decide whether id shall be grouped by (so to get one line per id, which would make no sense here, because that would be every record of the table) or aggregated ( for instance: MIN(id) ) or not selected at all.